# How can I use CGContextRef to draw two separate shapes

Tags: ios, cocoa, drawrect, cgcontext

I'm suffering a problem for tons of time, which is simple drawing two separate shapes (e.g. rectangles)

Specifically, I have a data source which is an array, and this array contains sub-arrays that contain CGPoints. What I want to do is just draw paths based on each sub-arrays, and they must be separated for the others.

Here is my current code

```
// for each room
for (int i=0; i<rooms.count; i++) {

    // configurations
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0f);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinBevel);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor);

    // create sub-path
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // get the points, at least 3
    NSArray *corners = rooms[i];

    // get the initial point
    CGPoint initialPoint = [corners[0] CGPointValue];
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);

    // draw paths
    for (int j=1; j<corners.count; j++) {
        CGPoint nextPoint = [corners[j] CGPointValue];
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
    }

    // once finish, add the last line to the initial point
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);

    CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // all done, release the path
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
    CGPathRelease(pathRef);
}
```

In other word of my problem. the first shape last point will have a path with the second shape first point, while the first shape last point has a path to second shape first point.

Is there anyone can help me find where is the problem of the logic?

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw a single item.

```
CGContextMoveToPoint
CGContextBeginPath
  CGContextMoveToPoint // (repeat as needed)
CGContextClosePath
CGContextStrokePath
```

To draw multiple polygons, just repeat the whole block.

It seems like your problem is missing the `CGContextMoveToPoint` before you begin your second path. If you don't move to a new point, your path will begin at the end of your last polygon. From the documentation on `CGContextClosePath`

> After closing the subpath, your application can begin a new subpath
>   without first calling CGContextMoveToPoint. In this case, a new
>   subpath is implicitly created with a starting and current point equal
>   to the previous subpath’s starting point.

Comment: I've tried either add CGContextMoveToPoint to a random place before starting new path, or starting a new path after move to the initial point of the next polygon, still not work. I believe that there should be some problem in the logic of my code.

Comment: OK, that's kind of embarrassing, the mistake comes from the process that I generate the array. Your answer is correct, now I'm able to draw separated polygons. Thanks a lot